# compute the wight of each tag for each item in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array like below:

```
 item   tag
 1      2
 1      3
 2      1
 3      2
 3      2
 3      4
```

I want to compute the weight of each tag for each item in array.
for example the weight of tag 2 for item 3 is 0.66, while the weight of tag 2 for item 1 is 0.5.
Is there a simple way in matlab to do this?

Comment: Could you be more precise on what you want as an output? if weigth of tag 2 for item 3 is 0.66, shouldn't the weight of tag 2 for item 1 be 2 instead of 0.5?

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior I want to compute the weight of each tag for each item separately. Item "1" has two tags("2,3"), so the weight of tag "2" for item "1" is 0.5, and item "3" has three tags("2,2,4"), so the weight of tag "2" for item "3" is 0.66.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a fancy solution but is what you need.

```
    item = [
                  1      2
                  1      3
                  2      1
                  3      2
                  3      2
                  3      4
                            ];

    items = unique(item(:,1));
    tags = unique(item(:,2));
    ind = 0;
    weights = zeros(size(items,1) * size(tags,1),3);
    for idx = items'
    for idx2 = tags'
    ind = ind + 1 ;
    weights(ind,:) = [idx,idx2,(sum(item(:,1) == idx & item(:,2) == idx2)) / sum(item(:,1) == idx)];
    end
    end
    weights(weights(:,3) == 0,:) = [];
    weights = [{'Item','Tag','Weight'};num2cell(weights)]

    weights = 

    'Item'    'Tag'    'Weight'
    [   1]    [  2]    [0.5000]
    [   1]    [  3]    [0.5000]
    [   2]    [  1]    [     1]
    [   3]    [  2]    [0.6667]
    [   3]    [  4]    [0.3333]
```

Comment: Your code would be much more legible if it was indented properly. If you select the code in the Matlab editor and press `Ctrl-I` it will do it for you automatically.

Comment: @beaker thanks for your response, But I have a large dataset and when I run this code, the "weights" array dimensions becomes 54000000*3 and Matlab stops working. Isn't there a more optimal way?

Comment: @mdf I'm not the one who wrote the answer, but I suspect more information about your dataset would be required. Such as: What is the total size of your dataset? How many unique items are there? How many unique tags? How many tags are expected for each item?

Comment: @beaker I have used one of MovieLens datasets, it has 5908 unique items and 9079 unique tags, so the "weights" matrix dimensions becomes 53638732*3 and Matlab stops working.